# What is the math behind Avoid High, Medium, low in Network Analyst and can it be changed ?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network, multimodal-network

When you are creating the network, in the attribute section you can define restrictions. Of such restrictions are Avoid High,Medium, Low and Prefer High, Medium, Low can someone mathematically explain what happens here and if it can be altered? I couldn't find info elsewhere.

Comment: A Boolean data type http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Understanding_network_attributes/00470000000m000000/GUID-4BAE3856-0B23-4D4B-937F-7C2B01FEB426/ The Math http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations

Comment: Thank you, I have read those but I need to understand how the difference between Prefer High and Prefer Medium is defined for example.

Comment: The closest I can find documented is from http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00480000000s000000 where it says "Numeric values that are greater than one cause restricted elements to be avoided; the larger the number, the more the elements are avoided. Numeric values between zero and one cause restricted elements to be preferred; the smaller the number, the more restricted elements are preferred. Negative numbers prohibit restricted elements." This leads me to believe it's a weighting factor in the overall solver algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The cost is multiplied by the following values:

- Avoid: High: 5
- Avoid: Medium: 2
- Avoid: Low: 1.3

Instead of these three preset values, you may type in a numeric value if you wish.

Source: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/using-parameters-with-network-attributes.htm